# Changing colours so I can see Eclipse debugging

Tags: eclipse, debugging, variables, colors

I've got an issue in Eclipse where I can't see the debugging variables.

Below is a screenshot.

Is is possible to change the color of the theme somehow. I've looked in Eclipse, but it's using global theme variables.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fq6dkf57jdmkn6b/screenshot2.png

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't think this is a color problem. I think this is an Eclipse bug unfortunately. Personally, when I hit an Eclipse debugging issue that I can't solve, I resort to jdb. It's very primitive but it works. Or I just put in some log statements.

Comment: I can actually make it work if I change the theme for the OS. I'm using Zorin Os based on Ubuntu.

If I set everything to user Ambiance theme the background for the variable debugging changes color.

Guess that has to do for now.
Thanks for your reply.